# What to replace the KeyEvent?

Tags: android, multithreading, keyevent, onkeydown

Basically, I want to have the spinning wheel load up immediately when the activity starts up, and then disappear when it is finished. However, in my current code, it only starts when I press a key. How should I replace the onKeyDown method so that everything starts up automatically?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Working", "Fetching Grades", true, 
            false);
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
public void run(){
    //String userthat = userThing.getText().toString();
    //String passthis = passThing.getText().toString();
    thisthing = new ClientLoginForm(user2s,pas2s);
    try{
        grades +=thisthing.returnGradies();
    } catch (Exception e){
        grades +="Connection Problems";
    }
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
private Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        pd.dismiss();
        tv.setText(grades + "\n " + pas2s + " " + user2s);
    }
};
```

Comment: So why are you putting the code in onKeyDown() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put onkeyDown() code into activities onResume() It will help you to solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify what it is that you want it to do?
Do you want a progress dialog to show while you load your app or do you want it to show while it fetches something?

-=UPDATE=-
Okay, as I see it, you are trying to do different things in your code.

If you want it show the dialog as soon as you start the activity, then you need to put the code from onKeyDown in too your onResume, as mentioned above.

But if you are trying to make a dialog that appears when you select something. e.g. a person from a list, then you are doing it correctly.

And last, if you are doing both, then i would suggest you making a method for making the dialog and so on, and then calling this from both the onKeyDown, and the onResume

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want to do. I want to have the progress show as I get data from thisthing.